# How to sum values of an array with products and values and order from smallest to largest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner in JavaScript and I'm rendering a list that contains some products.

A product contains several sizes and each size has its price.

I would like to know how to sum the prices of the different sizes for each product. To order in ascending order, starting from smallest to largest.

What I would like is, for example, joining all sizes of `product 1` to get the total value, adding up all sizes of `product 2` and getting the total value and so on. After that, order all products in ascending order.

I tried using the `reducer` function. But as inside each product it contains an array with the respective sizes and prices. I didn't know how to do it.

I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sum-and-order-list-l22l4?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import { useStyles } from "./styles";

const Products = (props) => {
  const { product } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginBottom: "10px"
      }}
    >
      <span style={{ fontWeight: 600, marginBottom: "10px" }}>
        Sizes:{" "}
        <span style={{ fontWeight: 300 }}>
          {product.sizes.map((cat) => (
            <div className={classes.boxItem}>
              <span className={classes.boxFooterName}>{cat.name}</span>
              <span className={classes.boxFooterPrice}>
                {cat.price !== 0
                  ? (cat.price / 100).toLocaleString(undefined, {
                      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                      maximumFractionDigits: 2
                    })
                  : "Free"}
              </span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which code is specifically your attempt at writing what you need?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off site just to do an initial review of your issue. Demos are great but only as support for what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: Hey guys, sorry, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sum of prices I would do:

```
const prices = {};

data.forEach(({ sizes }) => {
  sizes.forEach(({ name, price }) =>
    prices[name] ? (prices[name] += price) : (prices[name] = price)
  );
});

console.log(prices);
```

And to order the data in ascending order:

```
const compareElements = (product1, product2) => {
  const product2Sizes = product2.sizes.map(({ name }) => name);
  const firstMatchingSize = product1.sizes.find(
    ({ name }) => product2Sizes.includes(name) && name !== "Sample"
  );
  const product2Size =
    firstMatchingSize &&
    product2.sizes.find(({ name }) => name === firstMatchingSize.name);

  return firstMatchingSize &&
    product2.sizes &&
    firstMatchingSize.price > product2Size.price
    ? 1
    : -1;
};

const sortedProducts = data.sort(compareElements);
```

Comment: hey Agustin, sorry but I think I explain wrong, What I would like is, for example, joining all sizes of product 1 to get the total value, adding up all sizes of product 2 and getting the total value and so on. After that, order all products in ascending order. I updated my question. Sorry again

Comment: Hey Agustin, I have to create a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314909/how-to-sum-values-of-an-array-with-products-and-values-and-order-from-ascending