# How to sum values of an array with products and values and order from ascending?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner in JavaScript and I'm rendering a list that contains some products.

A product contains several sizes and each size has its price:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "5286",
    name: "Alyssa Ashley White Musk",
    description: "Sensual but not overpowering",
    categories: ["Fresh"],
    sizes: [
      {
        name: "Sample",
        price: 0,
      },
      {
        name: "Normal",
        price: 4000,
      },
      {
        name: "Large",
        price: 6500,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "6298",
    name: "Euphoria",
    description:
      "Euphoria by Calvin Klein is a woody, oriental scent has notes of pomegranate, black violet, black orchid, and mahogany.",
    categories: ["Floriental"],
    sizes: [
      {
        name: "Normal",
        price: 7100,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "9201",
    name: "Emporio Armani",
    description:
      "Emporio Armani by Giorgio Armani bottles style and sophistication for women all over the world to enjoy.",
    categories: ["Floriental"],
    sizes: [
      {
        name: "Sample",
        price: 0,
      },
      {
        name: "Normal",
        price: 2700,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default data;
```

What I would like is, for example, sum all sizes of product 1 to get the total value. Sum all sizes of product 2 and getting the total value and so on. After obtaining the sum of all products. Sort the list in ascending ones.

I tried using the `reducer` function. But as inside each product it contains an array with the respective sizes and prices. I didn't know how to do it.

I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sum-and-order-list-l22l4?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include a [mre] directly here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be good to add `totalSize` key (which contains the sum of item sizes) on each item using `Array.map` and sort that using `Array.sort`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "5286",
    name: "Alyssa Ashley White Musk",
    description: "Sensual but not overpowering",
    categories: ["Fresh"],
    sizes: [
      {
        name: "Sample",
        price: 0,
      },
      {
        name: "Normal",
        price: 4000,
      },
      {
        name: "Large",
        price: 6500,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "6298",
    name: "Euphoria",
    description:
      "Euphoria by Calvin Klein is a woody, oriental scent has notes of pomegranate, black violet, black orchid, and mahogany.",
    categories: ["Floriental"],
    sizes: [
      {
        name: "Normal",
        price: 7100,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "9201",
    name: "Emporio Armani",
    description:
      "Emporio Armani by Giorgio Armani bottles style and sophistication for women all over the world to enjoy.",
    categories: ["Floriental"],
    sizes: [
      {
        name: "Sample",
        price: 0,
      },
      {
        name: "Normal",
        price: 2700,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = data.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  totalSize: item.sizes.reduce((sum, cur) => (sum + cur.price), 0)
})).sort((a, b) => a.totalSize - b.totalSize);
console.log(result);
```